# Detect which child was clicked from parents onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that contains many img elements. The table registers for the onclick event & when it receives the onclick event I want to determine which img was clicked(if any).

I know I could just place a onclick event in each img element then I'd know if they were clicked but it also involves writing alot of long lines that pass the same information(repeating code -see below for what I mean).

So is there a way to look at the event object passed in the onclick event to determine which img element was clicked? If not maybe theres a way to do a hittest/collision test? Or maybe you know of another way?

```
<table onclick="openslideshow( event, new Array("img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"), "Author SlideShow");">
    <tr>
        <td><img class="screenshot" src="img1.png"/></td>
        <td><img class="screenshot" src="img2.png"/></td>
        <td><img class="screenshot" src="img3.png"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I place an onclick event on each img it uses ALOT of repeating code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img onclick="openslideshow( this, new Array("img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"), "Author SlideShow");" class="screenshot" src="img1.png"/></td>
        <td><img onclick="openslideshow( this, new Array("img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"), "Author SlideShow");" class="screenshot" src="img2.png"/></td>
        <td><img onclick="openslideshow( this, new Array("img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"), "Author SlideShow");" class="screenshot" src="img3.png"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Heres my function to attempt to determine which img element was clicked(when the table triggers the onclick event):

```
function openslideshow(evt, slideShowSrcs, dialogTitle)
{
    var selImg = evt.relatedTarget; // will this give me the clicked img & NOT the table?
    ... my code to open a JQuery dialog & show all slideShotSrcs in a sliding treadmill
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using jQuery so you can use the baked-in event delegation functionality:

```
$('table').on('click', 'img', function () {
    //now `this` refers the the image being clicked
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LMzeB/1/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and for versions between 1.4.2 and 1.7 you can use `.delegate():

```
$('table').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    //now `this` refers the the image being clicked
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LMzeB/2/

You can also use the `event` object supplied to event handlers:

```
$('table').on('click', function (event) {
    //event.target is the initial target of the element
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LMzeB/

Answer (score 3):

Use `evt.target`. This will give you the element that was clicked.

If you set a variable to that value, you can use it in the future to grab the `src` like so:

```
var elem = evt.target,
    elemSrc = elem.src;
console.log( elemSrc );
```

Comment: @JakeM: It should. But it's easier to use jQuery's built in `on()` function, like Jasper pointed out.

Comment: `event.which` gives you the key pressed I believe. For instance when using a mouse `event.which` returns `1` for left-button-clicks and `2` for mouse-wheel clicks. `event.target` is what I think you were going for... `event.which` is commonly used to determine which keyboard key has been pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of placing onclick on every img element, you can do as below in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
     $("img.screenshot").click(function() 
     {
         openslideshow( $(this), new Array("img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"), "Author SlideShow");
     });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Taking into account Jasper's comment, you can pass `this` or `$(this)` to the `openslideshow()` function. But you have to adjust the operations inside the openslideshow() function according to that.

Comment: Good suggestion. However you are passing in `$(this)` to the `openslideshow` function and the OP's code is just passing in `this`; which is the DOM element rather than a jQuery object that contains the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery would be the best bet here.

```
$("table img").bind("click",function(){

    // the clicked image is $(this)

    //get the href
    var clickedImageHref = $(this).prop("href");

});
```

Comment: `href` is an attribute, so `.attr('href')` would be perferred. The main difference (I believe) is that `.attr()` returns a value relative to the base-url of the document and `.prop()` returns the whole URL (like `this.src`).

Comment: Isn't `attr()` deprecated though?

Comment: @Purmou nope, `.live()` was depreciated as of 1.7 (maybe that's what you were thinking about) but `.prop()` was introduced in 1.6 `as a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes`: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ (this link has a nice table that describes when to use each function)